# OpenEars - fliteDidFinishSpeaking not called the first time Flite is fired

Tags: iphone, xcode, openears

A list, since it's easier to write:

• Music starts playing
• Skip to next track
• Flite speaks song title
• `fliteDidFinishSpeaking` doesn't fire -- Why?
• Hit Play to start the music -- `[musicPlayer play];` is at the end of the failing method
• Skip to next track (or just wait for the song to finish)
• Flite speaks the title of the last song -- not taking the new argument for `say:`
• Music restarts -- From this point on, Flite doesn't have trouble
• Skip to next track
• Flite speaks normally
• Music restarts

This only happens when the app is first launched, so there's something wrong with the initializing, either in my code or in OpenEars/Flite itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force seems to be working pretty well:

```
- (void)fliteWillStartSpeaking {
    [self resetFliteController];
    [fliteController say:@"some words" withVoice:curVoice];

    fliteDidFinish = NO;
    fliteFinishTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kFliteTimerCycle
                         target:self selector:@selector(forceFliteDidFinish)
                         userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)forceFliteDidFinish {
    if (!fliteDidFinish) {
        [self fliteDidFinishSpeaking];
    }

    [fliteFinishTimer invalidate];
}
```

A proper fix would be ideal, if anyone has found one.